# Bitcoin transaction stuck as unconfirmed with no fee

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I could have sworn when i tried withdrawing BTC to my local BTC wallet i set the fee to 0.005
The blockchain shows no fee was paid and the transaction is hanging with 0 confirmations.
I really am trying to get this BTC ASAP. 
Any ideas? Here is the transaction link.

https://blockchain.info/tx/0b30583b830a7ee674dd92f0a22b3d4b21c81b5f80687b2ad2e6b951a64ef4e2

Also: the transaction seems to be moving BACK in the queue

Comment: Looks like it has 40 confirms now.otherwise you could basically do a double spend of those coins and send the transaction with a fee. The transaction with the highest fees would get integrated more rapidly. From there the transaction with the lower fee would bounce be negated.

Comment: you need to create a raw transaction. Brain wallet has a nice utility to do so(but never use that address again afterwords) http://brainwallet.org/#tx . This is a handy tool to broadcast a raw transaction once you generate it as well.

Comment: @JoeWhite, But the bitcoin client wouldn't allow you to double-spend the coins right? I have a situation like his, are the coins *stuck* then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already resolved itself.